# CSS loader does not start animating

Tags: css, loader

I am unable to make the css loader from here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-loader-newtons-cradle work in jsfiddle, here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4eUrG/ 
  I looked more at their source code and they seem to use some javascript to make it start, is that really needed?

It uses the html:

```
  <div class="cord leftMove">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cord">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cord">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cord">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cord">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cord">
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cord rightMove">
    <div class="ball" id="first"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="shadows">
    <div class="leftShadow"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="rightShadow"></div>
  </div>

  <br><br>
  Inspired by <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/963799-Animation-Loading-gif">Jordi Verdu</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700);

body{
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  background: #ede9de;
  color:#666;
}

a, a:visited, a:hover{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#db5989;
}
a:hover{
  color:#a05772;
}

.container {
    height: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -53px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 106px;
  text-align:center;
}


.cord{
  padding-top:100px;
  width:15px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin:50% 50%;
  float:left;
}


.ball{
  background:#333;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  float:left;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.shadows{
  clear:left;
  padding-top:20px;
  margin-left:-2px;
}

.shadows div{
  float:left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width:13px;
  height:3px;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
  background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.3);
}

.leftMove{
  animation: leftBall .5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}
.rightMove{
  animation: rightBall .5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}


.leftShadow{
  animation: leftShadowN .5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; 
}
.rightShadow{
  animation: rightShadowN .5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; 
}


@keyframes leftBall
{
0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
/*this pauses the ball at the begining*/
50% {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
100% {
  transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-20px);
  }

}

@keyframes rightBall
{
0% {
  transform: rotate(-50deg) translateY(-20px);
  }
/*this pauses the ball at the begining*/
50% {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
  }
100% {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px)
      translateX(0px);
  }

}

@keyframes leftShadowN
{
0% {
transform: translateX(0px);


  }
/*this pauses the ball at the begining*/
50% {
  transform: translateX(0px);

  }

100% {

transform: translateX(-25px);
  }

}

@keyframes rightShadowN
{
0% {
  transform: translateX(25px);
  }
/*this pauses the ball at the begining*/
50% {
  transform: translateY(0px);

  }

100% {
  transform: translateY(0px);

  }

}


/*colors*/

.cord:nth-of-type(1) .ball{
  background:#335672;
}
.cord:nth-of-type(2) .ball{
  background:#35506b;
}
.cord:nth-of-type(3) .ball{
  background:#5f4e60;
}
.cord:nth-of-type(4) .ball{
  background:#924a4e;
}
.cord:nth-of-type(5) .ball{
  background:#a73a33;
}
.cord:nth-of-type(6) .ball{
  background:#cf4231;
}
.cord:nth-of-type(7) .ball{
  background:#df3e2a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works on IE10.

In order to make it works in webkit based browser, you need to specify it in the css for `transform` and `animation`

**Here for exemple :**

```
.leftMove {
    animation: leftBall .5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
    -webkit-animation: leftBall .5s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}
```

**And here too :**

```
@keyframes leftBall {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    /*this pauses the ball at the begining*/
    50% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-20px);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftBall {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    /*this pauses the ball at the begining*/
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg) translateY(-20px);
    }
}
```

You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eUrG/1/) for a complete update that works.